# Perepetual blocking of multiprocessing.Pipe()'s recv when using os.write

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe

For some reason, the following code blocks forever

```
read, write = multiprocessing.Pipe()
os.write(write.fileno(), b"test\n")
print(read.recv())
```

but this does not

```
read, write = multiprocessing.Pipe()
write.send("test\n")
print(read.recv())
```

As far as I can tell, `multiprocessing.connection.Connection.send` just calls `os.write` under the hood, so to my eye there should be no reason for this not to work. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. To anyone who finds this when googling, CPython sends the size of the data as a header, which means it is waiting for an amount of data equal to the big-endian representation of 'test'.

You can see the evidence for this [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c2368cbc83ca2bafeaea0e4760be4996046d0444/Lib/multiprocessing/connection.py#L406-L411) and [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c2368cbc83ca2bafeaea0e4760be4996046d0444/Lib/multiprocessing/connection.py#L390-L404).